# C++ can't call same function twice with different parameters

Tags: c++, function, runtime-error, runtime

I have a C++ program that calls the same function `tempGauge()` twice. It hits the first call then skips the second call and goes to `userData()` and gives me the error "finished with exit code 6". when I comment out the first call the second call works as expected and ends with the exit code 0.

```cpp
int tempGuage(int &array, int &actDay);
void userData();

int main() {
    const int totalTemp(10);
    int firstDay[totalTemp];
    int secondDay[totalTemp];
    int dayOne = 1;
    int dayTwo = 2;
    tempGauge(firstDay[totalTemp], dayOne);
    tempGauge(secondDay[totalTemp], dayTwo);
    userData();
    return 0;
}

int tempGauge(int &array,int &actDay)
{
    int i;
    int maxTemps;
    for(i=1;i < maxTemps;++i)
    {
        cout << "Enter # of temps on DAY " << actDay <<":";
        cin >> maxTemps;
        if(maxTemps <=0||maxTemps>=11)
        {
            cout << "Enter at least 1 but no more than 10. Try again.";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Enter the " << maxTemps << " temps(s):";
            cin >>array;
            i++;
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: That’s hardly ever possible. Either it does call `tempGauge` the second time but that call does not do what you expect, or it doesn’t call `userData` because it crashes earlier.

Comment: @numzero I edited my code when I comment out the first call the second call works fine and exits with code 0

Comment: There is one obvious bug in the shown code; unfortunately because it fails to meet the requirements for a [mre], it is not possible to authoritatively determine whether this is the only problem, or not. It is likely not the reason for the crash, actually, so pointing it out would be a waste of time until you read [ask] questions, [edit] your question, and fix it so that it shows a [mre].

Comment: Passing `firstDay[totalTemp]` and `secondDay[totalTemp]` are bugs. You are passing a reference to an integer that is 1 past the end of the array.

Comment: as well as using `maxTemp` before initialization

Comment: as well as passing array element instead of an array. The real array reference is written like `int (&array)[length]` IIRC, but length must be a compile-time expression, and must match length of the referenced array. Alternatively, plain pointer like `int *array` may be used. At the call site, plain `firstDay` is OK, no indexing necessary.

Comment: @drescherjm how would I fix this to pass the right parameter?

Comment: I would recommend you to use `std::vector` or `std::array` if you can instead of plain arrays. `std::array` doesn't have overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has **undefined behavior**.

Both of your calls to `tempGuage()` are passing in invalid `int&` references in the 1st parameter, as the `[totalTemp]` index is accessing an `int` that is *beyond the bounds of each array*.  So, even if `tempGauge()` worked properly (which it doesn't), it would be filling in invalid memory.  Since you clearly want to fill the arrays, you need to change `[totalTemp]` to `[0]` instead so you start filling at the beginning of each array rather than at the end.

Inside of `tempGauge()`, `maxTemps` is *uninitialized* when entering the loop, so the number of iteration is *indeterminate*.  But, even if it weren't, the statement `cin >>array;` does not read in an entire array, like you are expecting. Even if it could, it would not know how many `int`s to read, since `array` is declared as a reference to a single `int` and you can't pass `maxTemps` to `operator>>`. You would need a loop to read each `int` individually, which you are trying to do, but you are not looping correctly.  And also, `cin >> array` would need to be changed to `cin >> array[i];`, which won't work unless `int &array` is changed to either `int (&array)[10]` or `int *array`.  In which case, `main()` would then have to be updated accordingly, by dropping the `[0]` when passing in each array.

With that said, try this instead:

```cpp
#include <limits>

const int totalTemp = 10;

int tempGuage(int (&array)[totalTemp], int actDay);
void userData();

int main()
{
    int firstDay[totalTemp] = {};
    int secondDay[totalTemp] = {};
    tempGuage(firstDay, 1);
    tempGuage(secondDay, 2);
    userData();
    return 0;
}

int tempGuage(int (&array)[totalTemp], int actDay)
{
    int maxTemps;

    cout << "Enter # of temps on DAY " << actDay << ":";
    do
    {
        if (!(cin >> maxTemps))
        {
            cout << "Invalid input. Try again.";
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
        else if ((maxTemps <= 0) || (maxTemps > totalTemp))
        {
            cout << "Enter at least 1 but no more than " << totalTemp << ". Try again.";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Enter the " << maxTemps << " temps(s):";
            for(int i = 0; i < maxTemps; ++i)
            {
                while (!(cin >> array[i]))
                {
                    cout << "Invalid input for temp " << i+1 << ". Try again.";
                    cin.clear();
                    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    while (true);

    return maxTemps;
}

void userData()
{
    //...
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/8kBvmv)

Comment: how would I make them valid references?

Comment: do you mean like this `userTemp( firstDay[0], dayOne);`

Comment: why am I returning maxTemps? not the array?

Comment: In `c++` you can't return this type of array. if you have used std::array you can return that. With that said you don't need to return the array.

Comment: @normx222 because you can't return an array, only a pointer to an array, but the caller already has the array so returning it is pretty useless. But the caller needs to know how many elements of the array were actually filled in, and that is a good use for the return value.